# Slightly weaker notion of total boundedness and separability

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, separable-spaces

We know that a metric space $(X,d)$ is said to be totally bounded if for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there are finitely many points $\{x_{1}, \dots, x_{k_{\varepsilon}}\}$ such that $X \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{k_{\varepsilon}} B_{\varepsilon}(x_{n})$.

Now, what if we were to alter this definition to change *finitely* many points $x_{i}$ to *countably* many points $x_{i}$? When we prove that every totally bounded space is separable (i.e. we can find a countable dense subset), we never really use the fact that total boundedness gives us finite covers of every possible radius, but only that we get countable covers of every possible radius. It is, however, possible that I'm missing something. My question: is it possible to get separability from the weaker notion of total boundedness that I have described above?

Comment: A space satisfying that weaker condition is separable but note that it is now not even necessarily bounded.

Comment: It's more a uniform version of Lindelöfness, enough for separability (Lindelöf and separable are equivalent for metric spaces anyway) but not a good generalisation for the compactness applications of usual total-boundedness.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a space which satisfies your weaker condition is separable.

For every $n$ let $\{B^i_n\}_{i\in\Bbb{N}}$ be countably many balls of radius $1/n$ covering $X$ and let $\{q^i_n\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ be their centers. I claim that $$D=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}\{q^i\}$$ is a countable dense set.
Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary and let $\varepsilon>0$, we want to find a $y\in D$ with $d(x,y)<\varepsilon$. Let $N$ be  big enough such that $1/N<\varepsilon$, by hypothesis there is a ball of radius $1/N$ containing $x$, so its center is the $y$ we're looking for.

Comment: (Note that this exact argument works for totally bounded spaces as well)